# Performance issue in windows 2008 R2 64bit with Apache and IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, apache-2.2

I have a website that was behaving very well with windows 2003 32bit server with IIS6 and Apache 2.0, lately I upgrade to Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 with IIS7 and the same Apache 2.0 (32bit).
I'm noticing that after 50-70 users are connected, the response time extremely decreases. 
In the IIS logs the response time is perfect. It seems that the problem is the Apache.

Any Ideas ???

Comment: Need more info.  Apache config files, what they're serving, and why you have them configured in this way.

Comment: I am confused. IIS and apache both are web servers. Why you need IIS and apache together? How do you integrate them?